# Create Report using Crystal Report XI from DataSet

Tags: crystal-reports, dataset, crystal-reports-xi

**STEP 1.**My program get Crystal Report (XI sp6) templates from admin. It parses the templates to get SQLs from that and then populate it to get DataTables for each SQL.
**STEP 2.**After that, it push the DataTables back into the ReportDocument to create the report by using the following code:

```
// there no subreport in our template
//mainDS include all populated DataTable having the same name of related CR Command Alias
foreach (Table tab in doc.Database.Tables)
    tab.SetDataSource(mainDS.Tables[tab.Name]);
```

The problem is (I wonder if it is a Crystal Report Bug): if there is 2 Command in the template, when the code `tab.SetDataSource(mainDS.Tables[tab.Name]);` is executed for doc.Database.Tables[0] then `doc.Database.Tables[1].Fields` is become the same to `doc.Database.Tables[0].Fields` and ofcause I get an error.
I do not get this error with all templates, just some :(. All templates worked well in Crystal Report GUI!!!
Please help if it not bug or please show me how to work around!
I am using Crystal Report XI Developer Edition with latest pack, VS2005. Oracle 10g, Devart DotConnect for Oracle Free version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After mining SAP document and test many times, I think that it is a bug of CR XI R2 sp6. So I on report I only keep 1 Command, If there is a need for other commands, I will create subreports and put the commands in these.